# Socket.io not working with nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io

I'm trying to use `socket.io` with my `nginx` reverse proxy server, but it seems not working..

Chrome showing this wonderful waterfall:

screenshot:

[image]

and server's response is always like this:
`96:0{"sid":"UU9d1DfZL5RD29kAAACq","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}2:40`

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name socket.my.domain;

  ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.my.domain/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.my.domain/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1027/;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_buffering   off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  # This line.
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }

  location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1027/socket.io/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_buffers 8 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  }
}
```

socket.io server:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(1027);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log('connected');
});
```

front-end javascript:

```
let socket = io("https://socket.my.domain");

socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id);
});
```

Server keep logging the message 'connected', but client doesn't log the message.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: After a long time, I finally solved it.
NginX and Node.js server weren't a problem either.
The socket.io version of the client and server were different, so the connection could not be established without any errors.

Comment: This sounds very atypical... doesn't the socket.io server usually serve it's own client?